# Sistema conversao de url youtube para embed

Tags: php, mysql, youtube, vídeo

Boa tarde, estou a tentar criar um sistema, em que recebo num formulario um url youtube, converto para embed e guardo numa base dados. Trata-se de um site de classificados, nao sei se esta e a melhor forma, nao queria despender de muito espaço do alojamento por isso optei por videos do youtube, ser melhor pedir diretamente ao utilizador o link embed, se nao alguem pode me explicar como criar o sistema de conversao?
Obrigado.

Comment: Você pode gravar só o código do vídeo do youtube no banco de dados, e na hora de exibir, dentro do while você insere o código inteiro do embed, e apenas troque o /embed/D_E58tNUJRs  pelo /embed/<? echo $row['youtube']; ?>

Answer (score 1):

Link embed do youtube: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/[id_do_video]`
Exemplo: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/D_E58tNUJRs`

E no caso de conseguir os videos recentes do youtube utilize o GoogleAPI e recolha o link do feed dos vídeos recentes/mais classificados.

Aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613903/youtube-api-v3-get-list-of-users-videos tem este link que pode te ajudar em relação a procura de videos dos canais.

E para adicionar o valor ao banco de dados (estarei utilizando o mysql nesse caso, por ser menos complicado de trabalhar) utilize isso [php e mysql]:

```
<?php 
// conecta com o servidor 
$mysql_conexao = mysql_connect(servidor, usuario, senha);

// prepara o comando
$exec = "INSERT INTO nome_da_tabela (coluna1, coluna2) VALUES (value1, value2)";

// executa e verifica o comando 
if($mysql_conexao->query($exec) == TRUE){ //inserido com sucesso! }

?>
```

Comment: só lembrando coluna1, coluna2 serão no caso os nomes das colunas.

Comment: o mesmo é com o values1, values2

Comment: Obrigado, a minha duvida era mais no sistema de conversao